# Instantiating an Array of Objects, but it is working like static objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, static, instantiation

So i initialize an array of polynomials.

```
Polynomial* pArray;
pArray = new Polynomial[size];

for (int r = 0; r < size; r++){
    pArray[r] = Polynomial(p.size);
}
```

When i change the coefficients of any polynomial in pArray, it changes all of them.

```
pArray[1].coefficients[0] = 12;
cout << pArray[1].coefficients[0] << "\n";
//print coefficients
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < p.size; j++){
        cout << pArray[i].coefficients[j] << " ";
        }
```

Output:

```
12 0 12 0 12 0
```

I don't want this to happen. When I set one polynomial's coefficient i dont want it to affect the others. How do i do this?

Comment: Show the definition of `class Polynomial`.  What is `p`?

Comment: I'm going to bet this is a [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090) violation.  The line `pArray[r] = Polynomial(p.size)` invokes default assignment or copy construction on a class that probably does not support it, despite managing its own memory.

Comment: Hi, take a look at [mcve] and try clean up the question a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've shown, it looks like `coefficients` is probably a pointer initialized by the constructor `Polynomial(int)`.  From the behavior you describe, I'm certain enough of this that I'll answer your question even though you haven't shown the class.

Here's what it almost certainly looks like.  Here I'll assume it stores `int` values:

```
class Polynomial {
public:
    Polynomial() : coefficients(nullptr), size(0) {}
    Polynomial( int s ) : coefficients(new int[s]), size(s) {}
    ~Polynomial() { delete [] coefficients; }
    int * coefficients;
    int size;
};
```

And so now here is the problem.  You have violated the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090) by not providing a copy or assignment constructor for a class that manages its own memory.

When you do this:

```
for (int r = 0; r < size; r++){
    pArray[r] = Polynomial(p.size);
}
```

Here is what happens:

1. A temporary value is constructed by `Polynomial(p.size)`
2. The current `pArray[r]` value is destructed
3. The assignment operator is invoked, which by default will trivially copy data members from the temporary directly into `pArray[r]`
4. The temporary value from step 1 is destructed.

Note step 4.  You copied the *pointer* into another object, and then deleted that pointer.  Now you have *undefined behavior*.  In your case, what probably happened is that the call to `new` always gave back the same pointer.  That isn't guaranteed.  Nothing is guaranteed when you have undefined behavior.  But it does give away a strong hint that led me to write this answer.

To fix this, you must define a copy constructor for your object, which allocates a new `coefficients` array and copies the data into that.

```
Polynomial::Polynomial( const Polynomial & p )
: coefficients( new int [p.size] )
, size( p.size )
{
    std::copy( p.coefficients, p.coefficients+size, coefficients );
}
```

Or even better, store your coefficients in a `std::vector`.  You are using C++, after all.  Then you don't need to worry about new, delete, copies, or *moves* (a concept which I have decided to omit from this answer).

If you *must* allocate, then at least store the pointer as a `std::unique_ptr` -- that will then immediately give you a compile error when you attempt to copy your object, and force you to make a non-trivial copy constructor.